# Spring Webflux with Log4j2

Tags: log4j, log4j2, spring-webflux, slf4j

Quick question about the combination of Spring Webflux and Log4j2.
For organizational reason, I **must** use Spring Webflux **with log4j2**. Our support team will even refuse to support the app if they cannot see a log4j2.xml in the project.

Please, my question is not to challenge that, I like my support team, and whoever made this rule. I come here with a genuine question, regardless of above, why is my application not log4j2?

By that, I mean I can see this on start up.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.13.3/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.13.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

Also, **I do not see my log file anywhere**. (But on IntelliJ, I do see logs on the console)

Here are my log4j2.xml, my pom.xml, and a dummy boot app. The three combined can reproduce the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>question</groupId>
    <artifactId>question</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Hoxton.SR8</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-statemachine-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
               <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %5p - [%10.10t] %-30.30c{1.} : [%X{X-B3-TraceId}, %X{X-B3-SpanId}] %m%n%ex
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="/logs/question.log"
                     filePattern="/logs/log4j2-demo-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="ACCESS_LOG" fileName="/logs/access.log"
                     filePattern="/logs/access-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="question" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
        </Logger>
        <logger name="reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ACCESS_LOG"/>
        </logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class QuestionApplication {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(QuestionApplication.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuestionApplication.class);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/question")
    public ResponseEntity<Mono<String>> question() {
        LOGGER.info("I am not in any log file :'( please help");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(Mono.just("question"));
    }

}
```

And I start my app with:

```
java -Dlog4j2.contextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector -Dreactor.netty.http.server.accessLogEnabled=true -jar myjar.jar
```

And here is the dependency tree:

```
15:14:47 -          [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.26:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.11.2:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.11.2:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.11.2:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:0.9.12.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.52.Final:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.52.Final:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.52.Final:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.52.Final:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.52.Final:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.52.Final:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.52.Final:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.52.Final:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.52.Final:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.52.Final:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.52.Final:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |        \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.52.Final:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  \- org.synchronoss.cloud:nio-multipart-parser:jar:1.1.0:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     \- org.synchronoss.cloud:nio-stream-storage:jar:1.1.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  +- com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:jar:4.6.1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  +- com.datastax.oss:native-protocol:jar:1.4.10:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  +- com.datastax.oss:java-driver-shaded-guava:jar:25.1-jre:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.3.4:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-posix:jar:3.0.50:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-ffi:jar:2.1.10:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:1.2.19:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:native:1.2.19:runtime
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:7.1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:7.1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:7.1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:7.1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-a64asm:jar:1.0.0:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-x86asm:jar:1.0.2:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-constants:jar:0.9.12:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.javatuples:javatuples:jar:1.2:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:4.1.12.1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  +- com.esri.geometry:esri-geometry-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tinkerpop:gremlin-core:jar:3.4.5:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.tinkerpop:gremlin-shaded:jar:3.4.5:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.jcabi:jcabi-manifests:jar:1.1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- com.jcabi:jcabi-log:jar:0.14:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.squareup:javapoet:jar:1.8.0:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- net.objecthunter:exp4j:jar:0.4.8:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tinkerpop:tinkergraph-gremlin:jar:3.4.5:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tinkerpop:gremlin-driver:jar:3.4.5:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:indy:2.5.7:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:jar:indy:2.5.7:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  \- com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-annotations:jar:3.1.12:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |     \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- com.datastax.oss:java-driver-query-builder:jar:4.6.1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.3.10.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.13.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.13.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.13.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.5.5:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
15:14:47 -          [INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j:jar:1.0.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.64:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.64:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-circuitbreaker-resilience4j:jar:1.0.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-circuitbreaker:jar:1.3.1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  +- io.vavr:vavr:jar:0.10.2:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  |  \- io.vavr:vavr-match:jar:0.10.2:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-core:jar:1.3.1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-timelimiter:jar:1.3.1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  \- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-reactor:jar:1.3.1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.6:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-core:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.6:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave:jar:5.12.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-context-slf4j:jar:5.12.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-messaging:jar:5.12.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-rpc:jar:5.12.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-spring-web:jar:5.12.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     |  \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-http:jar:5.12.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-spring-rabbit:jar:5.12.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-kafka-clients:jar:5.12.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-kafka-streams:jar:5.12.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-httpclient:jar:5.12.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-httpasyncclient:jar:5.12.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-spring-webmvc:jar:5.12.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     |  \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-servlet:jar:5.12.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-jms:jar:5.12.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-metrics-micrometer:jar:2.15.0:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:jar:2.21.1:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.15.0:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-brave:jar:2.15.0:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-kafka:jar:2.15.0:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-activemq-client:jar:2.15.0:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-amqp-client:jar:2.15.0:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.2:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.2:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.2:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.12:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |     \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.14:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.16.1:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:jar:5.6.2:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.6.2:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.13:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.3.3:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.7.0:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.6.2:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.6.2:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.6.2:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.6.2:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.6.2:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.3.3:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.14:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.14:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
15:14:47 -          [INFO] +- org.springframework.statemachine:spring-statemachine-core:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] +- de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client:jar:2.3.0:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  \- de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-client:jar:2.3.0:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:jar:1.4.6:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-core:jar:1.4.6:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |  \- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-common:jar:1.4.6:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models:jar:2.1.4:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.1.4:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-integration:jar:2.1.4:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     |  \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:jar:2.1.4:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.11.2:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     |     \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     +- io.github.classgraph:classgraph:jar:4.8.69:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.10:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  +- org.webjars:swagger-ui:jar:3.32.5:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] |  \- org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:jar:0.45:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO] \- com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:jar:3.0.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO]    \- com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot:jar:3.0.3:compile
15:14:47 -          [INFO]       \- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.3:compile
```

What can I do to make my application log4j2 please?
Any way to see the actual log files? To make the SLF4J message disappear?
Is it possible to fix that without having to add exclusion everywhere in the pom?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you look at the output from SLF4J you will notice that logback is listed first so that is the implementation that will be chosen. You should run mvn dependency:tree to determine which components are including logback as a transitive dependency and add an exclusion to them to prevent logback from being included.

Comment: Dependecy tree added @rgoers. Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to chose log4j2 instead, like via some kind of spring property, VM arguments, whatever simpler than going through the entire tree and excluding them from my POM with many exclusion block? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply exclude `spring-boot-starter-logging` from `spring-boot-starter-webflux` dependecy in maven `pom.xml` and add `spring-boot-starter-log4j2`.

Similarly like described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging#log4j2-configuration-logging